# I can not work with zeep in python - missing element CallbackURL error

Tags: python, django

I want to make a payment gateway in django with the zeep module.
I want to test this payment gateway using local hosting.
I got help from a site that produces payment gateways and wrote this code:

**`views.py`**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from zeep import Client

MERCHANT = '00'
client = Client('https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/services/WebGate/wsdl')
amount = 1000
description = 'تست درگاه پرداخت'
CallbackURL = 'http://localhost:8000/' #whatever! i am just testing

def send_request(request):
    result = client.service.PaymentRequest(MERCHANT, amount, description, CallbackURL)
    if result.Status == 100:
        return redirect('https://www.sandbox.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/' + str(result.Authority))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Error code: ' + str(result.Status))

def verify(request):
    if request.GET.get('Status') == 'OK':
        result = client.service.PaymentVerification(MERCHANT, request.GET['Authority'], amount)
        if result.Status == 100:
            return HttpResponse('Transaction success.\nRefID: ' + str(result.RefID))
        elif result.Status == 101:
            return HttpResponse('Transaction submitted : ' + str(result.Status))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Transaction failed.\nStatus: ' + str(result.Status))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Transaction failed or canceled by user')
```

I get the following error when I run the server:

> Exception Value:   Missing element CallbackURL
>   (PaymentRequest.CallbackURL)
>
> Exception
>   Location:C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py
>   in validate, line 280

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PaymentRequest endpoint expects more parameters than you are giving it - it wants Email and Mobile before CallbackURL. Since those are nillable, you're right that you don't have to provide them, but you do then need to tell zeep that the final value applies to the CallbackURL parameter - which you can do via keyword arguments.

```
client.service.PaymentRequest(MERCHANT, amount, description, CallbackURL=CallbackURL)
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, as a sign to future searchers that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line of code:

```
{{  CallbackURL = 'http://localhost:8000/' }}
```

You have to enter the exact address in front of `CallbackURL`.
So as `'http://localhost:8000/'` result it is wrong.

You must enter the exact URL after the localhost:8000/
example:

```
'http://localhost:8000/zarinpal/verify/'
```